# Classification or regression for deep Q learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, objective-functions, pytorch

DQN implemented at https://github.com/PacktPublishing/PyTorch-1.x-Reinforcement-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter07/chapter7/dqn.py uses the mean square error loss function for the neural network to learn the state -> action mapping :

```
self.criterion=torch.nn.MSELoss()
```

Could cross-entropy be used instead as the loss function? Cross entropy is typically used for classification, and mean squared error for regression.

As the actions are discrete (the example utilises the mountain car environment - https://github.com/openai/gym/wiki/MountainCar-v0) and map to [0,1,2] can cross-entropy loss be used instead of mean squared error? Why use regression as the state -> action function approximator for deep Q learning instead of classification?

Entire DQN src from https://github.com/PacktPublishing/PyTorch-1.x-Reinforcement-Learning-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter07/chapter7/dqn.py :

```
'''
Source codes for PyTorch 1.0 Reinforcement Learning (Packt Publishing)
Chapter 7: Deep Q-Networks in Action
Author: Yuxi (Hayden) Liu
'''

import gym
import torch

from torch.autograd import Variable
import random


env = gym.envs.make("MountainCar-v0")



class DQN():
    def __init__(self, n_state, n_action, n_hidden=50, lr=0.05):
        self.criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()
        self.model = torch.nn.Sequential(
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_state, n_hidden),
                        torch.nn.ReLU(),
                        torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_action)
                )
        self.optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr)


    def update(self, s, y):
        """
        Update the weights of the DQN given a training sample
        @param s: state
        @param y: target value
        """
        y_pred = self.model(torch.Tensor(s))
        loss = self.criterion(y_pred, Variable(torch.Tensor(y)))
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()


    def predict(self, s):
        """
        Compute the Q values of the state for all actions using the learning model
        @param s: input state
        @return: Q values of the state for all actions
        """
        with torch.no_grad():
            return self.model(torch.Tensor(s))



def gen_epsilon_greedy_policy(estimator, epsilon, n_action):
    def policy_function(state):
        if random.random() < epsilon:
            return random.randint(0, n_action - 1)
        else:
            q_values = estimator.predict(state)
            return torch.argmax(q_values).item()
    return policy_function


def q_learning(env, estimator, n_episode, gamma=1.0, epsilon=0.1, epsilon_decay=.99):
    """
    Deep Q-Learning using DQN
    @param env: Gym environment
    @param estimator: DQN object
    @param n_episode: number of episodes
    @param gamma: the discount factor
    @param epsilon: parameter for epsilon_greedy
    @param epsilon_decay: epsilon decreasing factor
    """
    for episode in range(n_episode):
        policy = gen_epsilon_greedy_policy(estimator, epsilon, n_action)
        state = env.reset()
        is_done = False

        while not is_done:
            action = policy(state)
            next_state, reward, is_done, _ = env.step(action)
            total_reward_episode[episode] += reward

            modified_reward = next_state[0] + 0.5

            if next_state[0] >= 0.5:
                modified_reward += 100
            elif next_state[0] >= 0.25:
                modified_reward += 20
            elif next_state[0] >= 0.1:
                modified_reward += 10
            elif next_state[0] >= 0:
                modified_reward += 5

            q_values = estimator.predict(state).tolist()

            if is_done:
                q_values[action] = modified_reward
                estimator.update(state, q_values)
                break

            q_values_next = estimator.predict(next_state)

            q_values[action] = modified_reward + gamma * torch.max(q_values_next).item()

            estimator.update(state, q_values)

            state = next_state


        print('Episode: {}, total reward: {}, epsilon: {}'.format(episode, total_reward_episode[episode], epsilon))

        epsilon = max(epsilon * epsilon_decay, 0.01)

n_state = env.observation_space.shape[0]
n_action = env.action_space.n
n_hidden = 50
lr = 0.001
dqn = DQN(n_state, n_action, n_hidden, lr)


n_episode = 1000

total_reward_episode = [0] * n_episode

q_learning(env, dqn, n_episode, gamma=.9, epsilon=.3)



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(total_reward_episode)
plt.title('Episode reward over time')
plt.xlabel('Episode')
plt.ylabel('Total reward')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't want to answer because I'm not 100% but there are some technical details that mean Q-learning function approximators must be trained according to the MSE loss.